# Optimization of C program with SLAB-like technologies

Tags: c, optimization, memory-management

I have a programming project with highly intensive use of malloc/free functions.
It has three types of structures with very high dynamics and big numbers. By this way, malloc and free are heavily used, called thousands of times per second. Can replacement of standard memory allocation by user-space version of SLAB solve this problem? Is there any implementation of such algorithms?

P.S.

1. System is Linux-oriented.
2. Sizes of structures is less than 100 bytes.
3. Finally, I'll prefer to use ready implementation because memory management is really hard topic.

Comment: Check out mine: https://github.com/bbu/Userland-slab-allocator :-)

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: Thanks, it will be very useful if I will implement my own SLAB.
Some ideas are intresting, and I'm not so strong in memory managment so it will be helpfull.

Comment: +1 for recognizing memory management is hard and asking for existing implementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only have three different then you would greatly gain by using a pool allocator (either custom made or something like [`boost::pool`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) but for C). [Doug Lea's binning based malloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) would serve as a very good base for a pool allocator (its used in glibc).

However, you also need to take into account other factors, such as multi-threading and memory reusage (will objects be allocated, freed then realloced or just alloced then freed?). from this angle you can check into [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) (which is designed for *extreme* allocations, both quantity and memory usage), [nedmalloc](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/) or hoard. all of these allocators are open source and thus can be easily altered to suite the sizes of the objects you allocate.

Comment: Question is tagged as 'C'. Presumably boost isn't available. (Oops, you said 'like boost::pool', sorry.) BTW, great links.

Comment: @Kaganar: thats why I said 'like', unfortunately I don't know any pool allocators off the top of my head other than `boost::pool`. but I'll amend it.

Comment: @Necrolis: Thanks, I'm thought about my own implementation, optimized for my aims, with memory re-usage and big grain allocation. But it seems like reinventing of bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more it's impossible to give you a good answer, but yes, managing your own memory (often by allocating a large block and then doing your own allocations with in that large block) can avoid the high cost associated with general purpose memory managers. For example, in Windows many small allocations will bring performance to its knees. Existing implementations exist for almost every type of memory manager, but I'm not sure what kind you're asking for exactly...

When programming in Windows I find calling malloc/free is like death for performance -- almost any in-app memory allocation that amortizes memory allocations by batching will save you gobs of processor time when allocating/freeing, so it may not be so important which approach you use, as long as you're not calling the default allocator.

That being said, here's some simplistic multithreading-naive ideas:

[This](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) isn't strictly a slab manager, but it seems to achieve a good balance and is commonly used.

I personally find I often end up using a fairly simple-to-implement memory-reusing manager for memory blocks of the same sizes -- it maintains a linked list of unused memory of a fixed size and allocates a new block of memory when it needs to. The trick here is to store the pointers for the linked list in the unused memory blocks -- that way there's a very tiny overhead of four bytes. The entire process is O(1) whenever it's reusing memory. When it has to allocate memory it calls a slab allocator (which itself is trivial.)

For a pure allocate-only slab allocator you just ask the system (nicely) to give you a large chunk of memory and keep track of what space you haven't used yet (just maintain a pointer to the start of the unused area and a pointer to the end). When you don't have enough space to allocate the requested size, allocate a new slab. (For large chunks, just pass through to the system allocator.)

The problem with chaining these approaches? Your application will never free any memory, but performance-critical applications often are either one-shot processing applications or create many objects of the same sizes and then stop using them.

If you're careful, the above approach isn't too hard to make multithread friendly, even with just atomic operations.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented my own userspace slab allocator, and it proved to be much more efficient (speedwise and memory-wise) than `malloc`/`free` for a large amount of fixed-size allocations. You can find it [here](https://github.com/bbu/Userland-slab-allocator).

Allocations and freeing work in O(1) time, and are speeded up because of bitvectors being used to represent empty/full slots. When allocating, the `__builtin_ctzll` GCC intrinsic is used to locate the first set bit in the bitvector (representing an empty slot), which should translate to a single instruction on modern hardware. When freeing, some clever bitwise arithmetic is performed with the pointer itself, in order to locate the header of the corresponding slab and to mark the corresponding slot as free.